# Setting up multiple websites on Apache Httpd renders one site only accessible

Tags: apache-httpd, https

I am planning to setup bugzilla and Orangescrum on one server. I did the following configuration in `httpd.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
        <Directory /var/www/html/bugzilla>
                AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
                Options +Indexes +ExecCGI
                DirectoryIndex index.cgi
                # AllowOverride Limit FileInfo Indexes
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/html/project>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

With this configuration everything works fine. `http://server-addres` returns Apache's index, `http://server-address/bugzilla` opens bugzilla and `http://server-address/project` opens orangescrum.

Now I have searched over the Internet and I found that setting up multiple websites works differently than I did by setting up individual virtual hosts like [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-centos-7) for example. I did as in the website and for some reason `http://server-address` returns bugzilla, `http://server-address/project` gives me not found. The `sites-enabled/bugzilla.conf` contents are

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    ErrorLog /var/www/bugzilla/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/bugzilla/requests.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/bugzilla>
            AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
            Options +Indexes +ExecCGI
            DirectoryIndex index.cgi
            # AllowOverride Limit FileInfo Indexes
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and `sites-enabled/project.conf` contents are:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/
        ErrorLog /var/www/project/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/project/requests.log combined
        <Directory /var/www/project>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Am I setting up the two websites correctly? What went wrong with my configurations?

Another issue is setting up `https` for both websites. I followed the instructions [here](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Https) on the `httpd.conf` I provided here and `https://server/bugzilla` opens as FTP server while `https://server/project` is still not found. Any idea on setting up `https` for multiple websites? Thanks!

Update: Do I really need multiple virtual hosts? I went with the first configuration I provided and everything works with the addition of the following for SSL:

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.key
ServerName https://ip-address
```

And all 3 adresses `https://ip-address`, `https://ip-address/project` and `https://ip-address/bugzilla` work fine as expected.

Comment: You are missing `ServerName` and/or `ServerAlias` directives.

Comment: This is a local server. What should I set these to? hostname? IP?

Comment: And the same for each vhost?